# Adding underscore in Regex in Bash

Tags: regex, bash

I am trying to validate database name like `command.sh databaseName` with-in given regex as parameter using bash script.

For example

```
dataBaseNameIsValid
data-BaseNameIsValid
-dataBaseNameIsNotValid
dataBaseNameIsNotValid-
```

And the following code is working:

```
if [ -z $1 ]; then
    echo "No database name given"
    exit 1
fi

DATABASENAME=$1

# check the DATABASENAME is roughly valid!
DATABASE_PATTERN="^([[:alnum:]]([[:alnum:]\-]{0,61}[[:alnum:]]))$"

if [[ "$DATABASENAME" =~ $DATABASE_PATTERN ]]; then
    DATABASENAME=`echo $DATABASENAME | tr '[A-Z]' '[a-z]'`
    echo "DATABASENAME: " $DATABASENAME
else
    echo "invalid DATABASENAME"
    exit 1
fi
```

Now I want to introduce underscore `_` as valid char as well, what I did, I have added `_` score to my regex like this:

```
DATABASE_PATTERN="^([[:alnum:]]([[:alnum:]\-_]{0,61}[[:alnum:]]))$"
```

This return `invalid DATABASENAME`.

What I might doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The dash needs to be last (and the backslash doesn't help here). Just switch the order between `-` and `_` to get a well-defined enumeration.

(The dash can also be the very first character inside a character class, or immediately after the negation operator in a negated character class.)